# How does GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV work for color data?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Can anybody tell me how exactly to use `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` as type parameter in `glVertexAttribPointer()`?

I am trying to pass color values using this type. What is the significance of "REV" suffix in this type? Does it require any special treatment in the shaders?

Comment: This question has been [answered on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726676/what-does-rev-suffix-mean-in-opengl/17726824?noredirect=1#17726824).

Answer (score 4):

`GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` is a packed integer data type. Elements of this type in a buffer need 32 bits of space, with the Z, Y, and X (or B, G and R) components packed respectively into ten bit chunks starting at the low bits (that is, Z is bits 0 through 9, Y is bits 10 through 19, et cetera). The W (or A) component is stored in the high two bits (30 and 31).

The "REV" suffix refers to the fact that the data is "reversed," because the Z component is stored in the least significant bits.

This format allows higher precision in the XYZ/RGB channels at the cost of precision in the W/A channel. The pipeline will unpack the channel data and apply normalization back to `[-1, 1]` (`[0, 1]` for the unsigned variant) if you ask for it (using the `normalized` parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer`). Other than that, and deciding in your shaders to accept them as normalized floating point values or their original fixed-point integer values, they should not require special handling.